# Eclipse's JavaScript formatter joins wrapped variable assignments

Tags: javascript, eclipse, formatter, word-wrap

Currently I'm struggling with Eclipse's JavaScript formatter settings (Eclipse Neon3 4.6.3, Spring STS 3.9.0). I have the following lines of code (desired outcome):

```
feature = {

    initAttachOverlay: function (multipleSelectionBoxInstance, productWorkingCopyIdToAttach) {
        var attachButton = $('#attachToMasterProductButton'),
            confirmationButton = $('div.button-bar button.save', this.attachCloneOverlay),
            cancelButton = $('div.button-bar button.cancel', this.attachCloneOverlay),
            closeIcon = $('div.titleBar span.icon-delete_outlined', this.attachCloneOverlay);
    }
}
```

When those lines are formatted, I end up with all variable definition lines joined:

```
feature = {

    initAttachOverlay: function (multipleSelectionBoxInstance, productWorkingCopyIdToAttach) {
        var attachButton = $('#attachToMasterProductButton'), confirmationButton = $('div.button-bar button.save', this.attachCloneOverlay), cancelButton = $('div.button-bar button.cancel', this.attachCloneOverlay), closeIcon = $(
                'div.titleBar span.icon-delete_outlined', this.attachCloneOverlay);
    }
}
```

Are there any settings that keep those lines as they are or that split variable definitions after each comma? I tried to change every meaningful setting on the "Line Wrapping" tab without success.

What I'm looking for is like "Insert new line after comma in variable declaration" as "Insert new line after comma in object initializer" in the "New Lines" tab.

Any help is much appreciated!